# How can I set user environmental variables (such as PATH) from a non-administrator account on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, path, environment-variables, non-admin

How can I set user environmental variables (such as PATH) from a non-administrator account on Windows 7?

On Windows XP I could go into the Advanced Settings in the System Control panel.  However, on Windows 7 I get asked to provide an Administrator password.

Comment: Just run this in Start->Run rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ah, found an answer at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931715

> To resolve this issue, modify the user
>   environment variables by using the
>   User Accounts item in Control Panel.
>   To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click **Start**, type **Accounts** in the **Start search** box, and then click **User
>      Accounts** under Programs.
>
>    If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a
>      confirmation, type the password, or
>      click Allow.
> 2. In the **User Accounts** dialog box, click **Change my environment variables**
>      under **Tasks**.
> 3. Make the changes that you want to the user environment variables for
>      your user account, and then click OK.

Comment: I don't see Tasks.

Answer (score 27):

You can search for 'edit environment variables for your account' should come up as a Control Panel item.
If a variable doesn't exist for the user i.e. 'PATH' you can create it.  You'll find that what you create as a user is merged with what is set by the system.

[image]

Comment: The advantage of this approach over the accepted answer is that admin privileges are not required to edit the environment variables for your account.

Comment: @Jthorpe: No. It was precisely because of permissions I went to search the topic and the accepted answer solved me the problem. If I went trough Control Panel >  System, it asked me for the admin login and when I got to the variables dialog, it even said "Environment variables for user **admin**". Then I followed the accepted answer approach, no logins asked, and it said "Environment variables for user **me**".

Comment: @sergiol, If you search from using "Search" item on the start menu or Cortana, (depending on your version of windows), you should look for an item that states "Edit environment variabiles for **your account**" with the literal text "**your account**", not the name of your account ("**admin**" in your example).  Only that option will not require an admin privileges...