# How can I set user environmental variables (such as PATH) from a non-administrator account on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables

How can I set user environmental variables (such as PATH) from a non-administrator account on Windows 10?

I am aware that there is a button for what I want: 
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtS84.png) But as I click it, nothing happens.

You may as well check out this forum [post](http://www.tenforums.com/general-support/30455-how-do-i-change-environment-variables-regular-user-account.html) for another guy who has the same problem.

I am running windows 10 pro v1511 build10586.545

**Edit:**
It was a bug of Windows 10. Updating to the newest Update (Anniversary Update) fixed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set user environmental variables (such as PATH) from a non-administrator account on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/165909/how-can-i-set-user-environmental-variables-such-as-path-from-a-non-administrat)

Comment: @DavidPostill the answer does not apply in windows 10, because, as i stated above, this button is dead

Comment: @InsOP Worked for me. I am using Version 1607 Windows 10 Professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you want is `setx.exe` (it's a command-line program). Use `setx /?` to get usage info, but for your use case it boils down to the following:

`setx MYVAR "The value of my variable"`

Note that `setx` doesn't update your current environment variables for the running program (i.e. CMD or Powershell); you'll need to also use the `set` command to update the variables in the shell.

Two other ways to do this:

1. Use PowerShell to call the .NET function `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(<varname>, <value>, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)` (you can substitute `1` or `"user"` for `[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User`; it's an enum)
2. Edit the registry directly. Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573817/where-are-environment-variables-stored-in-registry, the location is HKCU\Environment. You could, for example, add a value like this (using the `reg.exe` program): `reg add /v <VARNAME> /d <VALUE>`

If you want to update your per-user PATH without also adding the all-users (local machine) PATH values to your personal PATH, you'll need to get a little trickier. Using `reg query` or `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable(<varname>, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)`, you can get the current value from the registry, instead of getting the process's current value for PATH (which is a concatenation of the user and machine values). Using PS, you could even set this value to a temporary variable:

`set mypath $([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", 1))` creates a temporary (local, non-environment) variable called "mypath" and sets it to the current user-specific value of the PATH environment variable (Windows environment variable names are case-insensitive).

`echo $mypath` to make sure you got it correctly.

`set mypath ($mypath + ';C:\foo\bar'); echo $mypath` appends `C:\foo\bar` to the temporary variable and echoes the result back.

`setx Path $mypath` to update the environment variable with your concatenated string.

`set $env:Path ($env:Path + ';C:\foo\bar')` to also update the current PowerShell session, or just launch a new one from Windows Explorer (Start, taskbar, whatever).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a maybe a fix for this button I was talking about so I dont have to go to the registry or powershell to do this? And if not, which of the provided methods do change the environment variables permanently?

Comment: The most obvious fix is just to update. The "Anniversary update" (v1607, build 14393) is now available, and will probably fix your malfunctioning link; as with @Ramhound, it works for me. If that still doesn't work for some reason, try using your Windows install media to "repair" your installation, or just re-install.

Comment: Every method not explicitly stated to be used for the current process only will make permanent changes. That means `setx`, `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable`, and registry editing (such as `reg add`. However, these methods do *not* change the environment variables in the current process, which is why I also include info on doing that.

Comment: thanks - the anniversary update will take up to 3 months to fully rollout. It wont update automacally, but you can update it with this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), which ill do. Will give Feedback whether it works